# mount stripe element to element in component after *ngIf

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I have a stripe card and Iban that gets mounted to an element, but only if that payment type is selected. When I select a payment type from the radio buttons provided the type is loaded into a variable and the *ngIf shows the div element. I am getting a DOM element error when I try and use the mount method, is there a way to do this?

```js
  logChange(type){
    this.paymentType=type.toLowerCase();
    if(this.paymentType==='credit card'){
      return this.createCard();
    }
    if(this.paymentType='iban'){
      return this.createIban();
    }
  }
    createCard(){
    this.card = this.elements.create("card", {
      style: this.cardStyle,
      hidePostalCode: true
    });
    this.card.mount("#card-element");
    this.card.addEventListener("change", event => {
      this.cardComplete = event.complete;
      const cardErrors = document.getElementById("card-errors");
      if (event.error) {
        cardErrors.textContent = event.error.message;
        cardErrors.classList.add("visible");
      } else {
        cardErrors.classList.remove("visible");
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="payment-select">
                  <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select a Payment Option">
                    <mat-radio-button (change)="logChange(type);" *ngFor="let type of paymentTypes" [value]="type">
                      {{type}}</mat-radio-button>
                  </mat-radio-group>
                </div>
                <div class="payment-details">

                  <div *ngIf="paymentType==='credit card'" class="card">
                    <div id="card-element">
                    </div>
                    <div id="card-errors">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div *ngIf="paymentType==='iban'" class="iban">

                  </div>
                </div>
```

the error I get, which makes sense since the element is not registered at the time of component init is

```
InvoicePaymentComponent.html:45 ERROR IntegrationError: The selector 
  you specified (#card-element) applies to no DOM elements that are 
 currently on the page.
 Make sure th
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `*ngIf` instead of the `visible` class?

Comment: but the error I am having is coming from the line this.card.mound(#card-element). I have tested it by removing any of the error handling.

Comment: ah got it to work with Renderer2 isntead of *ngIf

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution by using [hidden] even though it is not the removing the container from DOM like *ngIf directive.

```
<div [hidden]="paymentType==='iban'" class="iban">
     // Stripe elements
</div>
```

or ng-show/ng-hide for angular.js